# Importing jQuery plugin 'jquery.shorten' in TypeScript/Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I want to use a jQuery plugin named [jquery.shorten](https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten) in Ionic project using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.shorten).

The command for installig it is `npm install jquery.shorten --save`.

I have successfylly included `jQuery` and I am able to use it in my project. But not able to use `jquery.shorten`.

Following is the code which I am using to inclide `jQuery` and `jquery.shorten`. It is in `app.module.ts` of angular project -

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.shorten';
```

The error which I am seeing in console is -

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "jquery.shorten"

I also tried following. This time all console error gone. But I can't find a way of using it.

```
import * as shortMe from 'jquery.shorten';
```

It should be used as `$(".dynamic-multiple-elements").shorten()`.

I have followed few [instructions](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc) to have it included. But nothing seems to be working.
I can see the folder `jquery.shorten` with required js file in `node_modules`.

I won't be able to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749411/using-jquery-plugins-in-angular-4-applications) as my elements are dynamic and many.

Comment: import 'jquery.shorten'; will look in the package.json and tries to load the file specified with "main". In case of jquery.shorten this is set to ''main": "jquery.shorten.js". Unfortunately, there is no such file on root level.

So I guess you have to import it via
`import 'jquery.shorten/src/jquery.shorten';`

Besides that, I wouldn't recommend to use jQuery in Angular at all.

Comment: What is the reason using jQuery with Angular4?

Comment: @Sebastian, I am working on an Ionic project. I tried to import `jquery.shorten` using specific path similar to what you have suggested. I am currently getting error saying `"jQuery" is not defined` even if I have imported it and included tyings for it. I will check different ways of importing it.

Comment: @Stwosch, jQuery is very rarely used in my project (2 line to be exact). It makes targetting little easier than Angular. But I am going to use two plugins, [jquery.shorten](https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten)(for collapsing large messages) and [enjoyhint](https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint)(for user guide).

I coudn't find any alternate solutions of above two, this is why I need to incliude jQuery in my project.

Comment: when does it say `jQuery" is not defined`? During compilation or when the application starts?

Comment: You could try the following:

`import 'jquery';`
`import 'jquery.shorten/src/jquery.shorten'`

`declare let $: any;`
`declare let jQuery: any;`

Comment: @Sebastian, yes its during compilation. It must be due to last line of `jquery.shorten` which has code like `(function($) { // all codes inside })(jQuery);`.

Comment: @Sebastian, I wrote following codes in sequence. 1. `import 'jquery'`, 2. `declare let $: any; declare let jQuery: any;` and 3. `import 'jquery.shorten/src/jquery.shorten';`. Still the code says `Runtime Error: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: @Sebastian, error message in details. As this is an Ionic project, the main page shows `Runtime Error: jQuery is not defined` and the console error shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Comment: I am lookign into [this solution](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/322), which is working till now. Let me test and I will reply further.

Comment: @Sebastian, @Leonardo, Do you think [`jquery.shorten`](https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten) is exportable like [`slick-carousel`](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)? I was comparing [jquery.shorten](https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten/blob/master/src/jquery.shorten.js) and [slick-carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js) and found differences.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093807/easiest-and-shortest-way-possible-to-use-jquery-in-angular-2-4

Comment: @Vadamadafaka, I am able to successfully import and use `jQuery library`. My question is, "How to import old jQuery plugins". In this case it is `jquery.shorten`. I have managed to implement same feature by creating a function inside the Component class in Angular. I will add it to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45748427/4920091) how to use the of JQuery and other third-party globals in Angular.

To simple way without `InjectionToken`, you can do:

`npm install jquery --save.`

`npm install jquery.shorten --save.`

Add two scripts reference in angular-cli.json

```
...
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "../node_modules/jquery.shorten/src/jquery.shorten.min.js"
],
...
```

If you dont use the angular-cli put the script in webpack.

In any component use:

```
declare let $ : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log($);
      $('#text').shorten();    
   }
}
```

Component html to test

```
<p id="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
```

Comment: Oh, I lokked at this answer before. At the first time it looked ind of complex to me. I am looking on a way of including it in simplest way. I am currently looking at [this solution](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/322) (which is kind of hack), but I will come back with best solution.

Comment: Ok, I simulated here with the simple way and works fine. I will update the answer.

Comment: Your solution looks promising (I haven't tested). But I want even better solution which doesn't require very specific paths. See what I have posted as an answer. It can be better if we can remove necessity of editing `webpack.config.js`. @Sebastian has suggested a good solution. But I am getting errors in console related with undefined jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what I have implemented ([using this](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/322)) which is working perfectly.

**1. app.module.ts -** So that my imports gets available in all components.

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery.shorten/src/jquery.shorten';
```

**2.** I added following codes to `webpack.config.js` -

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

**3.** Declared variables `declare let $: any;` and `declare let jQuery: any;` in `home.ts` where I want to use both `jQuery` and `jquery.shorten`

**Problem -** The file `webpack.config.js` is present under `node-modules` folder. There is a very good chance that it could get replaced while transfering codes or during reinstalling npm.

**Expectation -** Changes should remain even if project files get transfered.

I want solution similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159347/ionic2-how-to-use-jquery-plugin-in-page) if it is possible.

Comment: I want to have this issue solved in without any workaround. @Sebastian has provided almost similar solution. But for some reason we are getting error that `jQuery is not defined`.